# Show loading alert with SweetAlert2 without having to interact

Tags: typescript, promise, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Right now I have this code:

```
swal({
     title: 'Loading cars from data base',
     showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
     preConfirm: () => {
       return this.carsSvc.getCars().then((cars: ICar[]) => {
               this.setData(cars);
               resolve();
            });
    }
});
```

This code shows an alert, I have to press 'confirm' and then it shows a loading icon and closes when the loading is finished.
I want only the last part of this action, so I don't want to have to confirm the loading before it begins to load. I want the loading to start when the alert is opened and to close automatically when the loading is finished. Is this possible with [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io)?

Comment: FYI: You are creating an additional promise for no reason. Just return `this.carsSvc.getCars().then(cars => ...`

Comment: True. Thank you. I thought the resolve() function which is delivered was part of the alert pattern of sweetalert

Comment: Do you know where the resolve() function comes from in this example?

`preConfirm: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      $.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
        .done(function (data) {
          swal.insertQueueStep(data.ip)
          resolve()
        })
    })`

Comment: `resolve` is how you create a promise. It is used to signal successful completion and provide the value that the promise produces (if there is a value). You already have a promise, so you don't need to build one. Often, `resolve` is used to transform a non-promise-based api into a promise based one.

Comment: Got it. Thank u.

Answer (score 27):

you can also use this

```
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Please Wait !',
                html: 'data uploading',// add html attribute if you want or remove
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                onBeforeOpen: () => {
                    Swal.showLoading()
                },
            });
```

and for close It

```
swal.close();
```

Answer (score 16):

A little late probably but I figured this out. Try this:

```
swal({
     title: 'Loading cars from data base'
});
swal.showLoading();

this.carsSvc.getCars().then((cars: ICar[]) => {
           swal.close();
           this.setData(cars);
           // show a new success swal here?
        });
```

You want to call the `swal.showLoading()` method to disable buttons. You can then call `swal.close()` to finish.

Answer (score 16):

You can try to use this...

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Uploading...',
  html: 'Please wait...',
  allowEscapeKey: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  didOpen: () => {
    Swal.showLoading()
  }
});
```